# Conditionally enable validation of hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a 3-step wizard HTML form created in ASP.Net MVC. All fields are available in DOM all the time.

Step 1 and Step 2 have a 'Continue' button. Step 3 has a 'Save' button.

When the user clicks on 'Continue' I want only the visible elements to be validated. However in the final step, Step 3, upon clicking the 'Save' button. I want to validate all fields from all the steps.

```html
<button class='moveToNextStep' data-step='1'>Step 1</button>
<button class='moveToNextStep' data-step='2'>Step 2</button>
<button class='moveToNextStep' data-step='3'>Step 3</button>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".moveToNextStep").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let stepN = $(this).attr("data-step");
    SwitchTab(stepN)
  })
})

function SwitchTab(no) {
  switch (no) {
    case 1:
      //move to step 2
      break;
    case 2:
      //move to step 3
      break;
    case 3:
      //final submit
      $("#NewForm").validate({
        ignore: []
      }) //Not sure about ignore here, but I want to validate all fields in this step.
      $("#NewForm").submit();
      break;
  }
}

$("#NewForm").validate({
  rules: {} //all the rules
})
```

Comment: @AbhishekPandey, it is not just about being able to validate hidden fields, i can use ```ignore:[]``` for that. The problem I have is, I want to **conditionally** use this functionality.

Comment: You can't.  Once the form is initialized with the `.validate()` method, you cannot dynamically change any of the settings except the rules, and only by using the `.rules()` methods.  In other words, your code doesn't work because you're not allowed to call `.validate()` more than one time for initialization.  Since validation itself dynamically responds to whether fields are hidden or not, simply toggle your fields and validation will follow.

Comment: Also FYI, `ignore: []` means "ignore nothing" (validate everything including hidden).